# passing ArrayList<Parcelable> from one activity to another

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, arraylist, package, parcelable

I have a class called Boy which has an instance variable of type `ArrayList Question>`. Question on the other hand has 5 instance variables of type string. when I unwrap the `Arraylist Question>` I try to read one of Question's string values and instead of the actual value I get `com.example.test.Question@418a39e0` or similar text depending on the question i choose.

Why is this happening please?

This is class Boy

```
public class Boy implements Parcelable{
ArrayList<Question> questionList;

public Boy(){
    questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Question ques1 = new Question();
    Question ques2 = new Question();
    questionList.add(ques1);
    questionList.add(ques2);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Boy(Parcel in) {
    questionList = in.readArrayList(Question.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(questionList);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Boy> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<Boy>() {
    public Boy createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Boy(in);
    }

    public Boy[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Boy[size];
    }
};
}
```

This is class Question

```
 public class Question implements Parcelable{
public String ques = "how do you create a parcelable?";

public Question(){

}

public Question(Parcel in) {
    ques = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(ques);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Question> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<Question>() {
    public Question createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Question(in);
    }

    public Question[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Question[size];
    }
};
  }
```

This code show the class controlling the second activity. I am trying to unwrap the arrayList and read its one of the questions's content but instead of the actual text i am getting `com.example.test.Question@418a39e0`

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
String ques1;
String ques2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

    Boy b = (Boy)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("marcus");
    ques1 = b.questionList.get(0).toString();
    ques2 = b.questionList.get(1).toString();

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv1.setText(ques1);
    tv2.setText(ques2);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override toString() in the Question class to print out what you need.